# Terraform: How can I have one common output for all declared modules?

Tags: terraform

I have got something like this in my terraform file:

main.tf

```
    module "airflow_tenant_one" {
      source = "../modules/airflow_tenant"
      name   = "one-airflow"
      project             = var.project
      cluster_name        = var.cluster_name
      region              = var.region
      kubernetes_endpoint = var.kubernetes_endpoint
      tenant_domain       = "one-airflow.${var.domain_name}"
    }
    
    module "airflow_tenant_two" {
      source = "../modules/airflow_tenant"
      name   = "two-airflow"
      project             = var.project
      cluster_name        = var.cluster_name
      region              = var.region
      kubernetes_endpoint = var.kubernetes_endpoint
      tenant_domain       = "two-airflow.${var.domain_name}"
    }
```

How can I do one common output for all declared modules?

Currently, it looks like:

outputs.tf

```
    output "chart_name_one" {
      description = "The name of the chart"
      value       = module.airflow_tenant_one.chart_name
    }
    
    output "chart_name_two" {
      description = "The name of the chart"
      value       = module.airflow_tenant_two.chart_name
    }
```

I asked because in a future it is possible that I will add more modules in my `main.tf` file. Will be better to have one output declaration for all of them.

Comment: Do you mean dynamically? Or just that if you add a module you can also go and edit the output at the same time?

Comment: You could do ` value  = [module.airflow_tenant_one.chart_name, module.airflow_tenant_two.chart_name ]`, but its unclear what do you actually aim for.

Comment: Yes. I would like to do dynamically. I don't want to add every outpusts when I will add new module.

Answer (score 0):

The `module` blocks you shared seem like they are all systematically configured based on some client names, so you can potentially do this using a single `module` block with `for_each` if you are using Terraform 0.13.0 or later.

```
locals {
  tenants = toset([
    "one",
    "two",
  ])
}

module "airflow_tenant" {
  for_each = local.tenants

  name                = "${each.key}-airflow"
  project             = var.project
  cluster_name        = var.cluster_name
  region              = var.region
  kubernetes_endpoint = var.kubernetes_endpoint
  tenant_domain       = "${each.key}-airflow.${var.domain_name}"
}

output "tenant_chart_names" {
  value = {
    for name, tenant in module.airflow_tenant : name => tenant.chart_name
  }
}
```

The above will cause there to be one instance of the `airflow_tenant` module per element of `local.tenants`, with addresses like this:

- `module.airflow_tenant["one"]`
- `module.airflow_tenant["two"]`

The `for_each` makes the module behave as a map of instances when you refer to it elsewhere, which is why we're able to project that map in `output "tenant_chart_names"` to derive a map from tenant name to chart names.

You can add and remove elements of `local.tenants` over time, in which case Terraform will understand that as an intent to either create a instances or destroy an instances of all of the objects described inside that module.

You can read more about this feature in [Multiple Instances of a Module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html#multiple-instances-of-a-module).